# mongodb document grouping

Tags: mongodb

i have my test collection as given below..

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : "111-21212121", "Mawb" : "111-1111111", "Hawb" : "111111", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }
{ "_id" : "111-21212122", "Mawb" : "111-1111111", "Hawb" : "222222", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }
{ "_id" : "111-21212123", "Mawb" : "222-2222222", "Hawb" : "333333", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }
{ "_id" : "111-21212124", "Mawb" : "222-2222222", "Hawb" : "444444", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }
{ "_id" : "111-21212125", "Mawb" : "333-3333333", "Hawb" : "555555", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }
{ "_id" : "111-21212126", "Mawb" : "333-3333333", "Hawb" : "666666", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }
```

and i want to group(map/combine) it by "Mawb" key...
so that i can have output of grouped document like,

```
[
{ "_id" : "111-21212121", "Mawb" : "111-1111111", "Hawb" : "111111", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }
{ "_id" : "111-21212122", "Mawb" : "111-1111111", "Hawb" : "222222", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }],
[{ "_id" : "111-21212123", "Mawb" : "222-2222222", "Hawb" : "333333", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }
{ "_id" : "111-21212124", "Mawb" : "222-2222222", "Hawb" : "444444", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }],
[{ "_id" : "111-21212125", "Mawb" : "333-3333333", "Hawb" : "555555", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }
{ "_id" : "111-21212126", "Mawb" : "333-3333333", "Hawb" : "666666", "Hawb_date" : "date1" }]
```

I have tried for a map reduce but cant get it through. how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MongoDB 2.1 or later (2.1.x is the development series leading up to the 2.2.0 stable release expected soon), you can use the Aggregation Framework to do all of this on the server side.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework